# how to remove hover effect from these social icons

Tags: css

Please help me I don't know how to remove the hover effect from this CSS coding.
I try head but I failed

here the code I have provided
I just want to remove the Hover effect from this CSS coding.
I use this CSS on my website to show the social icons in the footer.

but the problem I have faced I am not able to remove the hover effect

```
.social .facebook a:before{content:"\f082"}
.social-bg .facebook a,.social-bg .facebook-f a,.social-bg-hover .facebook a:hover,.social-bg-hover .facebook-f a:hover{background-color:#3b5999}
```

Comment: pls share html and css

Comment: Prior saying you tried and didn't get the solution, you might need to check where you tried hard., add some more code for the better understanding along with the required output and the current output your code is giving you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove
.social-bg-hover .facebook a:hover, social-bg-hover .facebook-f a:hover

[image]

Comment: Why taking the trouble of uploading an image instead of providing textual code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these classes:
`.social-bg-hover .facebook a:hover,.social-bg-hover .facebook-f a:hover`

```
.social-bg .facebook a,.social-bg .facebook-f a{
     background-color:#3b5999;
 }
```